# ¿Cómo limitar el número de queries que un usuario puede ejecutar desde la consola de MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Una vez que un usuario es creado desde la consola de MySQL, con la siguiente sintáxis básica

```
CREATE USER 'god'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 
sha256_password BY 'password';
```

Posterior al usuario le asignas permisos, por ejemplo de este modo

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.* TO 'god'@'localhost';
```

Terminando con

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Aunque al usuario recién creado se le han asignado permisos únicamente sobre una base de datos, la pregunta es la siguiente

¿Cómo puedo limitar el número de queries que dicho usuario puede hacer a la base de datos a la cual tiene acceso, es decir delimitar por un periodo de una hora el tipo y máximo de acciones que puede ejecutar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos establecer por rangos de hrs. el máximo de queries o incluso de updates que un usuario puede realizar a una base de datos, a través de la siguiente sintáxis

**Dentro de la consola de MySQL podemos establecer permisos a un usuario del modo siguiente**

```
CREATE USER 'demon'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password
BY 'password'
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 30
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10;
```

Rescatamos lo siguiente:

> 1. Los valores que vamos a establecer como límites necesitan ir precedidos por la sentencia `WITH`
> 2. Los valores a los cuales vamos a indicar su límite no necesitan ir en un orden necesariamente
> 3. Todos los valores que se van a parametrizar por el rango de Hour, necesitan ser de tipo entero
> 4. Cada uno de los límites que pueden ser configurados deben ir con mayúsculas y con guiones bajos
> 5. El tiempo se medirá por enteros de horas